# C++ networking libraries require kernel stack

Tags: c++, network-programming, boost-asio, poco

Does C++ network libraries POCO, ASIO... all these use kernel tcp/ip stack or they use their own tcp/ip implementation? Does they invlove kernel provided tcp/ip stack when they are being used.

Comment: Of course they use what the OS provides...

Comment: I recommend you look at the source code for their implementations. I think you'll find it handy to see how they accomplish using the same API calls to accomplish the same things when the underlying system uses completely different API calls.

Answer (score 2):

`POCO` and `boost.asio` are portable `C++` libraries. They will use what the OS kernel provides for the network service. On Linux this is usually done through `C` library and system calls provided by the kernel, which is the interface for OS service.

Answer (score 0):

They wrap the OS stack, whatever that happens to be